# Use of xs:any in complex types containing elements with 1..1 cardinality

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to allow `xs:any` elements at the end of a complex type that has mandatory elements with a 1..1 cardinality.

Example:

```
<xs:element name="ComplexElement" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/> 
      <xs:element name="OtherAttribute" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will throw an error as the wild card would catch `Identifier`, which is only allowed once. I don't want to use `namespace="##other"` as the elements could be from the same namespace.

Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: Let me be more specific. XMLSpy is giving the following error when trying to save the schema:
"The schema doesn't appear to be valid by itself (as a part of another schema, it might still be OK).
The content model of complex type definition {anonymou} is ambiguous.
Details: cos-noambig: <any minOccurs="0"> makes the content model non-deterministic against <element name="Identifier" minOccurs="1">. Possible causes: name equality, overlapping occurrence or substitution groups"

Essentially I need a way to allow additional fields to be appended at the end of each complex type in the schema.

Comment: As I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32906735/290085), you have to make the leading elements mandatory ahead of the `xsd:any` in order to avoid UPA.   Or, as Michael Kay [points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32907814/290085), use XSD 1.1.   In what way do these two responses not completely answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `minOccurs="0"` from your `OtherAttribute` declaration.

If you want the `xs:any` elements at the end of the sequence, you'll have to make the elements before it mandatory, otherwise the parser will have to look further ahead than a single element to determine whether an `OtherAttribute` should satisfy the optional direct declaration  (currently `minOccurs="0"`) or the optional `xs:any` declaration.  If a validating parser has to look further ahead than a single element, you'll run afoul of "Unique Particle Attribution".

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.1, if an element matches both a specific element particle and a wildcard, the specific particle wins; there is no UPA conflict between a specific named particle and a wildcard.